# Wordpress : set a custom field in archive based on ACF date

Tags: wordpress, filter, advanced-custom-fields, posts, add-action

I created a custom field ACF named "date_dexpiration" with format : d/m/Y H:i

When I create a new post with no expiration date, the field "date_dexpiration" is not fullfilled and stays empty.

I want in an archive (created with elementor posts widget) set a custom filter in order to hide all the posts with a date "date_dexpiration" < today.
I wrote this code inserted in function.php

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/filter_expiration_date', function( $query ) {
    $today = date('d/m/Y H:i');
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );
    $meta_query = [
        [       
        'key'       => 'date_dexpiration', 
        'value'     => $today,
        'compare'   => '>=',
        ]
    ];
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
} );
```

It doesn't work:

- all the posts with empty field "date_dexpiration" aren't displayed
- all the field with filled field "date_dexpiration" aren't displayed

Can you help me please to debug this code.

Answer (score 0):

ACF default format for date fields is `Ymd` so you need to convert `$today` to `Ymd` format. Try this below code.

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/filter_filter_expiration_date', function( $query ) {
    $today = date('d/m/Y H:i');
    $today = date( 'Ymd', strtotime( $today ) );
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );
    $meta_query = [
        [       
        'key'       => 'date_dexpiration', 
        'value'     => $today,
        'compare'   => '>=',
        ]
    ];
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
} );
```

Comment: @Bruno Bros does my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.
I had to change a bit the code you gave.
Here is my last version:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/filter_expiration_date', function( $query ) {
        $today = date('Ymd');
        $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );
        $meta_query = [
            [       
            'key'       => 'date_dexpiration', 
            'value'     => $today,
            'type'      => 'DATE',
            'compare'   => '>=',
            ]
        ];
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
} );
```

It works fine when the ACF fieeld is fullfilled (for expired and not expired values), but not works when the field is not fullfilled or doesn't exist for a post. These posts are not displayed.

I tried:

```
if( get_field('date_dexpiration') ) ...
```

but doesn't work!

Do you know how to keep the first filter and had the other filter for all the non fullfilled items.

Thank you again.

Comment: What about `$meta_query = [ relation' => 'OR', [ 'key' => 'date_dexpiration', 'value' => $today, 'type' => 'DATE', 'compare' => '>=', ], [ 'key' => 'date_dexpiration', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS', ], [ 'key' => 'date_dexpiration', 'value' => '', ], ]; ` ?